# Select last record of each month for each ID

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I'm trying to pull the last record of each month for each ID.

Below is the table I'm requesting from:

```
myTable
ID  date         data
1   2020-08-27   a
1   2020-08-28   b
1   2020-09-30   c
2   2020-08-29   d
2   2020-09-30   e
```

I would therefore like to get the following:

```
output
ID  date         data
1   2020-08-28   b
1   2020-09-30   c
2   2020-08-29   d
2   2020-09-30   e
```

The "complexity" here is that the last record of each month might not be the same for each ID.

So far, I only managed to get all the records available on the last date in each month in the database with the following request:

```
SELECT ID, date, data
from myTable
and date in (SELECT max(date) FROM myTable GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m', date))
```

which gives me this

```
wrong output
ID  date         data
1   2020-09-30   c
2   2020-08-29   d
2   2020-09-30   e
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ROW_NUMBER() window function:

```
SELECT ID, date, data
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, strftime('%Y%m', date) ORDER BY date DESC) rn
  FROM myTable 
)
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is great. I didn't know about windows function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated subquery for filtering:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
and date = (
    select max(t1.date) 
    from mytable t1 
    where strftime('%Y-%m', t1.date) = strftime('%Y-%m', t.date) and t1.id = t.id
)
```

Another approach uses window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        rank() over(partition by id, strftime('%Y-%m', date) order by date desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The second option using windows option works great. The first one though does not, while more appealing at first glance because I didn't know windows function.

Comment: @GMB Both your queries don't work: `strftime('%y-%m', date)` returns `null` for any valid date in SQLite: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q5b2YyqvFz1E1ZfLK5vKT7/0 Also you 2nd query was posted after my answer because initially you posted only the 1st query and you added the 2nd later, although the edit timestamps do not save edits in such a sort time after the initial post of the question.

Comment: @forpas: ok, I fixed to `%y` to `%Y` (which I consider to be a typo...), thanks for that. That's a good reason why your answer should be accepted (not debating the post timestamps).